# Makefile, Compiling and Linking

Tags: c, compilation, linker, makefile

I have a question regarding compiling and linking in Makefile (and perhaps in general).

I have a server.c file which consists of the main program which has a `main()` function. `server.c` includes rio.c. I have a module called `rio` which consists of `rio.c` and `rio.h`. It has no `main()` function.

I have two questions, how to actually write the Makefile, and the best practice for doing such a thing.

**Q1: How to write the Makefile**

I have the following Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes
OBJS = server.o rio.o

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o sysstatd

server.o: server.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c server.c

rio.o: rio.c rio.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c rio.c

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o sysstatd
```

I am having linking issues with this. It says that I have multiple definitions of all the functions used in C. I'm not sure how this is possible since server.c is compiled with the `-c` flag so nothing is actually linked. It should know that some functions exist but not actually link them until the `all` rule compiles both object files together and produces a single object file which has everything linked.

What is the issue here?

**Q2: Best practice**
Since I have a module and then another file which contains the main program, should I compile the main program, `server.c`, as a separate module and then compile both together in `all`, or compile server.c in all and add the rio.o module there? Note that this still produces the same linking problem I have above so I'm pretty sure I have my issue lies somewhere else.

Comment: Are you using any external libraries?

Comment: Yes. But it is calling errors on my own functions saying server.c defined them first. server.c and rio.h both import: stdio.h, stdlib.h, unistd.h and errno.h

Comment: When you say, "server.c includes rio.c", do you mean that in the file `server.c`, you have a line like `#include "rio.c"`?  If so, that's the wrong approach to take and the likely source of the error; you should be including `rio.h` instead.

Comment: Not only that, but you also have to explicitly link the files in the make file. I'm pretty sure you'd be doing this after `-o sysstatd <L>` where `<L>` is the library to link. If you were to link `libsomelib.a` for example, providing it was in your `$PATH`, you would replace `<L>` with `-lsomelib`.

Comment: @JohnBode Yep that was the issue. That makes sense. My server.o already had the rio.c functions since it included rio.c, causing the linking error. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: The default link rule depends on the `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` variables just like the default c-compilation rule depends on `CFLAGS`. Making good use of those default rules is a way to make your makefile shorter and more idiomatic. In short, it helps to read the documentation.

Comment: @dmckee I read it.. Obviously I have `-c` and custom naming `-o` flags, hence, writing out the compilation lines.

Comment: The [default GNU make build rule for c source files is `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules). It would do just fine with the right choice of `CFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`. You would have to specify the link rule, but you should use the usual variables because that is what anyone reading your source will expect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should revise the structure a little:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes
OBJS = server.o rio.o

all: sysstatd

sysstatd: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o sysstatd

server.o: server.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c server.c

rio.o: rio.c rio.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c rio.c

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o sysstatd
```

The difference is that the phoney rule `all` depends on `sysstatd` being up to date, and `sysstatd` is up to date when it is up to date w.r.t the object files.

Now it is just rather verbose, writing the compilation actions explicitly.  It would be sufficient to use:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes
OBJS = server.o rio.o

all: sysstatd

sysstatd: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o sysstatd

server.o: server.c
rio.o: rio.c rio.h

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o sysstatd
```

You could also debate: does `server.c` not use `rio.h`?  If it does, the dependency should be listed.  If not, why does `rio.h` exist?  `make` will assume that `server.o` depends on `server.c`, so you don't have to specify that (but it won't make assumptions about the headers). You could also use a macro to prevent repetition of the program name:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes
OBJS = server.o rio.o
PROG = sysstatd

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@

server.o: rio.h
rio.o: rio.h

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o $(PROG) core a.out
```

If you needed other libraries, then you might use:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes
OBJS = server.o rio.o
PROG = sysstatd
LOCALLIBDIR = /usr/local/lib
LDFLAGS = -L$(LOCALLIBDIR)
LDLIBS  = -lone -ltwo

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

server.o: rio.h
rio.o: rio.h

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o $(PROG) core a.out
```

Comment: Hugely beneficial seeing it improved step by step like this. Thank you.